# My hard drive doesn't show up on my computer after I have installed windows 7

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

I have just installed windows 7 on my computer and on the install I was able to choose my two hard drives both my samsung and my ssd , I choosed my samsung and it installed without errors. But now while im on my computer my ssd hard drive isn't showing up in my computer nor can I install or find it anywhere! I had the same issue while trying to install windows on my ssd, then my samsung didn't show up ! Please if you have any answers or have had a equal problem respond to this!

Comment: It sounds like you don't have a driver or the correct driver. This is why it's not even showing up in Disk Management. Are you running 64 or 32 bit Windows?

Comment: Does it come up in the Device Manager?

Comment: @LeeTaylor: Im running 64 bit

Comment: @JohanEkman OK, What is the model of the Samsung drive? You'll need to find a 64-bit driver for your SSD.

Comment: @LeeTaylor: Its a samsung 840 series

Comment: Silly question: you dont happen to have one of those motherboards that allow ssd caching, do you?

Answer (score 5):

Its possible that you don't have a partition created on the disk (did you delete all the partitions from the disks when installing Windows7?).

To check that you need to to right click on *My computer* > *Manage* > *Disk Management*

[image]

Chose the disk that does not contain any partition and create a new one. Don't forget to assign it a letter or a mount path.

Another option is that the partition(s) exist on the disk and there is no letter assigned to it, in that case follow the instructions to get to the *Disk Management* tool, right click on the partition and choose *Change letter / paths* from the menu.

[image]

Comment: My ssd does not show up there either, there is only my samsung and something that was reserved for important files from windows, Its really weird because I had them both working perfectly before but then I used DBAN to wipe the computer and now its like this! Do you think the DBAN has something to do with it ?

Comment: on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qwDZ8bNFi3Q

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet may be to load up a Linux live CD (Ubuntu, Fedora, whatever your flavor), and format the nonexisitng HDD to NTFS using Linux.  I've seen this happen on a few occasions after installation, and I have had to format the HDD using another OS.

Comment: Hmm yea that might be a good thing to try! Ill give it a shot if nothing else does it!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to download the latest driver for your SSD :

http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/SW/201210/20121031161138928/Samsung_Magician_v.3.2_Setup.exe

Please download, install, and let me know if this works.

Comment: This drive actually finds the ssd but I'm not sure how to turn it on. I couldnt find any way of finding a way to activate it, but im glad it comfirms my ssd is in there atleast. Do you know of how I might be able to turn it on from here on ?

Comment: @JohanEkman Hi. Does your drive now appear in Disk Management? Does it appear in Device Manager?

Comment: :Neither, it appears in System information if I run the samsung ssd magician. It appears under Drive summary , not sure if I can unlock it from there